# How to get 'href' value of <a> element with jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

How to get `href` value of `<a>` element and store it to a variable with jquery mobile?

This is my snippet code:

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log("href value: |"+href);
});
```

Here is sample:

```
<a href="117.xx.xx.xx/timesheet/file.pdf">Link</a>
```

In my log cat (btw I am using jquery mobiel for phonegap), it returns : `href value: |#`

What i want is, something like this in my logcat:

```
href value: | 117.xx.xx.xx/timesheet/file.pdf
```

I'm using phonegap 2.9

Comment: can you show us the <a> you´re reading from?

Comment: Edited :) , please help me, I'm stuck with it.

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? .live() is deprecated in 1.7, this is really just a wild guess, but does it help if you use .on() instead? The $(this) refers to clicked <a> tag, so do you have <a> tags with href="#" in your code?

Comment: I'm using JQuery 1.7.2. OK I'll try your suggestion. I think I don't have one in my code. But, I'll check again.

Comment: Well, I tried .on instead of .live(), but it seem doesn't work too.Even, it doesn't call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved. After frustating with jquery 'live' and 'on', I'm using plain Javascript function to get value of link in attribute: `getAttribute('href')`. And that worked!! Anyway, thank's for all the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the symptoms you describe, it seems as though the `a` tag firing the click event has an `href` of #.  Possibly some other tag wrapping your intended anchor?  Try a more specific selector and see if that works, maybe something like:

```
$('#myLink').live('click', function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log("href value: |"+href);
});
```

With this for a link:

```
<a href="117.xx.xx.xx/timesheet/file.pdf" id="myLink">Link</a>
```

If it still gives you a #, then is it possible that the `href` value is populated after your click event is firing (possibly by some other javascript)?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion for using id instead of plain 'a'.